# Angular2 - why cant use dash or other special characters in property name

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

Why I can not use dash here?

```
export class FizzService {
  getFizzes() : object[] {
    return[
      {
        iconClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-search',
      },
```

So in above I can not use

```
icon-class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-search',
```

I must do:

```
iconClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-search',
```

Otherwise I see error:

[image]

Comment: Use quotes `'icon-class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-search'`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks, thats interesting. Could you explain why? Or maybe just post an answer , I will gladly accept it

Comment: That's a pure JavaScript issue. `-` is an operator in JS, and therefore can't be used within identifiers.

Comment: the parser will interpret dash as the subtract operator

Comment: @yurzui - Thanks again..

Comment: Javascript object properties with special characters (like `@` or `-`) need to be strings. To access these properties, you would write `object['icon-class']`, as `object.icon-class` would not work.

Comment: Using hyphens in HTML and CSS id/class names is a general convention (see Google style guides). Also prevents conflicts between JavaScript objects and HTML tag id's in global/window properties. All HTML element IDs are added to window object, and as JavaScript vars cannot have hyphens (except as string accessors), it helps with this conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property names can be strings (`"foo"`) or identifiers (`foo`).

Identifiers can also be used for variables.

Identifiers cannot include a hyphen because that is the *minus* operator.

`amount-discount` means "Amount minus discount" and not "A variable with a hyphen in the name".

Identifiers can't include spaces, `+` characters and a host of other characters either. Use a string if you want a property name to include a special character.

Answer (score 2):

It is because property of the Object should not contain any special characters except underscore(Eg: property_name).

If you want to use hyphen in the property of the object then we should be putting the property in quotes(Eg: "property-name").

Please go through the below link for naming conventions in javascript.
http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply place quotes around the property name with special characters i.e:

```
'ng-class':'glyphicon glyphicon-house'
```